# Filtering and queue the packet of a process using iptable

Tags: iptables, netfilter

I am trying to queue the packets of a process so I can use libnetfilter_queue to modify them.

I know that I should use `--pid-owner processid` to filter packets of a process and `iptables -I <table or chain> <match specification> -j NFQUEUE --queue-num <queue number>` to add them to the queue. However, I am confuse what value I should use for *"table or chain"* and *"match specification"* .

Because I am new to iptable, I have read the documentation but still I am not sure what value I should chose, as I want to queue the packets of an application regardless of its source and destination.

I would appreciate any suggestions that can help me to understand these two fields in a better way so I can select the right values for them to address my problem.

Comment: You didn't describe your application, but consider if moving the process into a network namespace wouldn't be a simpler alternative.

Comment: It's not an application written by me, I am trying to capture the packets of applications such as skype, firefox, chrome etc

Answer (score 1):

I meant "application" in the sense of "what do you want to do with it".

If you want to monitor network traffic of something complicated, that potentially has multiple processes and threads, I'd definitely recommend to put it in a network namespace, make a veth-pair into the main namespace, and then just capture on the veth pair with wireshark etc.

Here's a script a have for that as a starting point:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Setup network namespace with veth pair, start xterm in it

# nsterm ns0 veth0 10.0.0 yellow 24

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

NS=${1:-ns0}
DEV=${2:-veth0}
DEV_A=${DEV}a
DEV_B=${DEV}b
ADDR=${3-:10.0.0}
ADDR_A=${ADDR}.254
ADDR_B=${ADDR}.1
MASK=${5:-24}
COL=${4:-yellow}

# echo ns=$NS dev=$DEV col=$COL mask=$MASK

ip netns add $NS
ip link add $DEV_A type veth peer name $DEV_B netns $NS
ip addr add $ADDR_A/$MASK dev $DEV_A
ip link set ${DEV}a up
ip netns exec $NS ip addr add $ADDR_B/$MASK dev $DEV_B
ip netns exec $NS ip link set ${DEV}b up
ip netns exec $NS ip route add default via $ADDR_A dev $DEV_B
ip netns exec $NS su -c "xterm -bg $COL &" USERNAME
```

Replace `USERNAME` with your user, run as root like

```bsh
nsterm ns0 veth0 10.0.0 yellow
```

and you get `10.0.0.1/24` in the namespace `ns0`, `10.0.0.254/24` in the main network namespace, and a yellow xterm where you can start programs like skype, firefox, chrome.

In the main name space, you need to enable forwarding and masquerading, say to `wlan0`:

```bsh
echo "1" | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then `tcpdump -i veth0a`, or wireshark.

Comment: Thank you very much @dirkt. Well the  application  is that I would like to implement [This paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6821309/) in Linux . Where I need to capture each applications packets, modifying  their TOS field and then send the modified packet to its original destination. I believe your method might slow down the traffic rate. I have searched around and it seems the easiest way is to used netfilter.